# Unicode not recognised when running react native app on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, react-native

I have a this element in a react-native app I've been using to learn, based on the tutorial.   It renders fine in the desktop, on the iPad Pro simulator:

```
var MainPageTopBar = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.topBar}>
                <Text>{'\u25BC'} Jobs</Text>
                <Text>{'\u2795'}|{'\u{1F50D}'}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

However, when I follow [the instructions for running on device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content) (using the development server), I get:

```
SyntaxError: \u can only be followed by a Unicode character sequence

{   
    "line": 1146,   
    "sourceURL": "http://192.168.178.22:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"
 }
```

If I delete the unicode characters out of the above code, it works fine on the device.

What is going on here?

---

(I'd also like to know what line of what file that error message is referring to: IE how would I go about debugging this if I didn't already know where the unicode characters were?  Because there is no file I can find of that name, or with unicode at line 1446.)

Comment: Note: I have subsequently found that if I bundle the app (as also described in the same page) and run it completely on the iPad, it works.  It's only the "run using development server" approach that has this problem.  It's a hassle because the build-bundle-deploy process is rather clunky...